# Wine won't launch any apps returns error 0009:err:module:__wine_process_init failed to load L"Z:\\path\to\executable", error c000012f

Tags: wine, 19.10

I have tried purging, removing folders and reinstalling. Always same error.
Ubuntu 19.10 
AMD R7 360
Intel Core i7
Wine Staging 5.3

I have not used any sudo commands with wine. Folders are not locked from user in any way.

Answer (score 2):

That error code would be returned in at least one scenario: **invalid/corrupt executable**.

Here, I reproduce it with [EICAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) — which is invalid Win32 PE; rather, it's a DOS COM file:

```
$ echo 'X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*' > eicar-standard-antivirus-test-file
$
$ file eicar-standard-antivirus-test-file
eicar-standard-antivirus-test-file: EICAR virus test files
$ 
$ wine ./eicar-standard-antivirus-test-file
0034:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe" not found
002c:err:wineboot:process_run_key Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (126).
00a4:fixme:ntdll:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 24000 (device=2 access=1 func=0 method=0)
00ac:fixme:ntdll:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 24000 (device=2 access=1 func=0 method=0)
00ac:fixme:ntdll:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 24000 (device=2 access=1 func=0 method=0)
00ac:fixme:ntdll:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 24000 (device=2 access=1 func=0 method=0)
0024:err:module:__wine_process_init failed to load L"Z:\\home\\ulidtko\\eicar-standard-antivirus-test-file", error c000012f
```

You can tell Wine to log much more verbosely — read `man 1 wine`.

With the EICAR example, `env WINEDEBUG=warn+all wine ./eicar-standard-antivirus-test-file` would output plenty of complaints in header byte mismatches and invalid sizes, ending with `invalid ELF header` (which I guess was meant to say `invalid PE header`).

There of course might be (and probably are) other scenarios where error c000012f would be emitted... but this is definitely one of them. Hope it helps.